# Update an array stored in a cookie with a new value each time a page is loaded

Tags: php, cookies, refresh, setcookie

I'm attempting to keep an array of values stored in a cookie, and update that cookie with a new value every time the page is loaded, but I can't get the array to update. Here's what I've got so far:

I've set up an array with four values, and I'm selecting a random value in the array on each page load.

```
// Store values in array
$values = array(
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C',
    3 => 'D'
);

// Get a random value for this page load
shuffle($values);
$random_value = $values[0];
```

I then check if the cookie is set, and if it hasn't been set yet (e.g. the first time the page is loaded) I set the cookie to store the value, using JSON to store the value in an array.

```
// Check if cookie has been set
if (!isset($_COOKIE["my_cookie"])) {
    // Set cookie to current value
    $init_value = array($random_value);
    $init_value = json_encode($init_value, true);
    setcookie('my_cookie', $init_value, time()+3600);
}
```

I then have an else statement which will be triggered when the cookie has been set (e.g. every subsequent page load), which gets the cookie array, adds the current random value to the end of the array, and attempts to store the updated array as the new value of the cookie.

```
else {
    // Get cookie value
    $prev_value = $_COOKIE["my_cookie"];
    $prev_value = stripslashes($prev_value);
    $prev_value = json_decode($prev_value, true);
    // Add current value to array and set cookie again
    array_push($prev_value, $random_value);
    $new_value = json_encode($prev_value, true);
    setcookie('my_cookie', $new_value, time()+3600);
}
```

Everything works great up until the attempt to update the cookie with a new value in this last chunk of code. The value is added to the array, but the array isn't set as the cookie.

Can anyone tell me why the cookie isn't updated? And am I going about this in the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: you actually need to destroy your old cookie and make a "new" one.

Comment: use `setcookie('my_cookie', $new_exp, time()+3600);`. $new_exp is in single quote. so the value is not executed

Comment: @TamilSelvan I removed the single quotes, but the issue still remains.

Comment: I run your code, everything works fine for me.

Comment: I just tested it out by copying the code from stackoverflow, and it works! No idea what happened there, I think perhaps I fixed the issue in simplifying the code to post here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your code here, everything works perfectly. Try clearing cookies on your browser, possibly just a local problem

Answer (score 0):

You should set a path for `setcookie()` as complications can arise without it. Also, you've enclosed your variable in single quotes so it will never be evaluated and just treated as text, i.e...

`setcookie('my_cookie', $new_exp, time()+3600, '/');`

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong in this piece:

```
setcookie('my_cookie', '$new_exp', time()+3600);
```

First, I believe you meant to use double quotes here (it won't be evaluated otherwise). Second, wouldn't it always be null as you are using $new_exp before you define it? I believe you meant to do this (correct me if I'm mistaken)

```
setcookie('my_cookie', "$random_value", time()+3600);
```

Comment: I removed the single quotes.

I've added the `$random_value` to the `$new_value` array (name changed from $new_exp for consistency) using `array_push`, so I want to add this updated array, not just the value of `$random_value`.

Comment: Nevermind, I was confused because $new_value and setcookie were in the same line